# Oracle JDBC: underflow in double

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, double, precision

When trying to insert doubles into a **DOUBLE PRECISION** column of an Oracle table, I get an exception when the double is out of range (in my case: too small), but only when using `PreparedStatement` (if I use the normal `Statement`, it rounds the double to 0).

Table:

```
create table test
(
  VALUE DOUBLE PRECISION
);
```

Java code:

```
double d = 1e-234;

// using Statement works, the number gets rounded and 0 is inserted
try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
    stmt.executeUpdate("insert into test values (" + d + ")");
}

// using PreparedStatement fails, throws an IllegalArgumentException: Underflow
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into test values (?)")) {
    stmt.setDouble(1, d);
    stmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

- Do I have to check and round all doubles before using them in insert/update statements?
- Can I somehow have the values automatically rounded?

Thanks for any insights/hints.

Comment: Strange. According to Oracle documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.10.1.2/ref/rrefsqljdoubleprecision.html), the DOUBLE PRECISION type has the same limits as Java Double class: 
    Largest negative DOUBLE value: -1.7976931348623157E+308
    Largest positive DOUBLE value: 1.7976931348623157E+308
    Smallest negative normalized DOUBLE value: -2.2250738585072014E-308
    Smallest positive normalized DOUBLE value: 2.2250738585072014E-308
    Smallest negative denormalized DOUBLE value: -4.9E-324
    Smallest positive denormalized DOUBLE value: 4.9E-324

Comment: using DESCRIBE I can see that Oracle created the table column with an actual type of FLOAT(126)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DOUBLE PRECISION` = `FLOAT(126)` as you noted in the comment.

Use the `BINARY_DOUBLE` data type to have the same precision as a Java `Double`.

Reference:

- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21642/types.htm#TTSQL124

Answer (score 1):

That is expected because the double precision will be converted to number ultimately and number only supports range-`1E-130 .. 10E125`.

```
SQL> select to_char(to_number(1.0e-234)) from dual;

T
-
0

SQL> select to_char(to_number(1e-130)) from dual;

TO_CHAR(TO_NUMBER(1E-130))
----------------------------------------
1.000000000000000000000000000000000E-130
```

> **FLOAT:**
>
> A subtype of the NUMBER datatype having precision p. A FLOAT value is represented internally as NUMBER. The precision p can range from 1 to 126 binary digits. A FLOAT value requires from 1 to 22 bytes. [More...](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm)

From [AskTom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5011470313887)

> Doesn't show that floats aren't numbers, they are just a number with a different precision then number in itself.